# how to show html content in trNgGrid with $sce.trustAsHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a table with search options that uses trNgGrid.js. I make a query to a Sharepoint list where one of the columns has html content and I want to display this.

For doing this I use `$sce.trustAsHtml` inside the promise, but this is not working. So after some tests I notice that after doing the `$scope.requests.push(item)` I  can do something like this:

```
$scope.requests[x].SubjectText = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.requests[x].HTMLContent);
```

and this works more or less because the SubjectText column is not for showing html so what it does is to show it as plain text.

On the other hand, if I do something like this nothing happens:

```
$scope.requests[x].HTMLContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(angular.copy($scope.requests[x].HTMLContent));
```

And the column is without data. The most strange thing is that if I do exactly the same, but without telling to which item I put the value it works, so the html content is shown in a perfect way, but all items have the same value that is the last one from the promise.

```
$scope.requests.HTMLContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(angular.copy($scope.requests[x].HTMLContent));
```

I made a change in the trNgGrid that helps me to have a `ng-bind-html` in a div in case of having file-name.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a custom column where you can use an `ng-bind-html` directive:

```js
angular
        .module('myApp', ['trNgGrid'])
        .controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "$sce", function ($scope, $sce) {
            $scope.myItems = [
                     {
                         name: "Moroni", 
                         age: 50,
                         htmlContent: $sce.trustAsHtml('<i><b>HTML Content #1</b></i>')
                     },
                     {
                         name: "Tiancum", 
                         age: 43, 
                         htmlContent: $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="text-danger">HTML Content #2</div>')
                     },
                     {
                         name: "Jacob", 
                         age: 27,
                         htmlContent: $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="text-info">HTML Content #3</div>')
                     },
                     {
                         name: "Nephi", 
                         age: 29,
                         htmlContent: $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="text-warning">HTML Content #4</div>')
                     },
                     {
                         name: "Enos", 
                         age: 99,
                         htmlContent: $sce.trustAsHtml('<pre>HTML Content #5</pre>')
                     }];
            }]);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.0.3/slate/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/trNgGrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/trNgGrid.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <table tr-ng-grid items="myItems" fields="['name','age']">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><div></div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div ng-bind-html="gridItem.htmlContent"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you do not separate the HTML from the data (which I would always recommend), then you need the `fields` attribute in order to stop the grid from automatically picking up the `htmlContent` data member.

Comment: I want to display label as html element based on value of attribute **field-name** i.e if value of **field-name** is true if want to display label as <label  class="label label-success">yes</label> and if value of **field-name** is false then <label  class="label label-danger">no</label>
Please help me for the same